# facebook meta og:image doesn't show image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, metadata, meta

Why doesn't facebook show image.

This is debug link: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.dreamtravel.rs/sr-latn/jesen-2013/evropske-destinacija/italija/articles/2013/sep/17/venecija-shoping-tura/)

There is a meta tag, and image exist, but doesn't show it on debug.

Comment: Are you using permalinks? because I tried to open a parent directory it gives 404 error, make sure You are using an image that exists on server, not call it with a permalink

Comment: Image exist on server, go on [link](http://www.dreamtravel.rs/sr-latn/jesen-2013/evropske-destinacija/italija/articles/2013/sep/17/venecija-shoping-tura/) and view source, you'll see url of og:image, and it is: http://www.dreamtravel.rs/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/fb/72/fb72a099-f7e8-4e19-9cf8-4170cf04aef1/download.jpg__300x250_q85_autocrop_crop_replace_alpha-%23fff_upscale.jpg and it is correct. But facebook doesnt recognize it?

Comment: Can you try another image? Your image URL is very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image URL was strange, i used django filer thumbnail and it generate image.
Now it works with regular image url.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but I've been having the same problem even though Facebook debug would report no issues and finally fixed it.

Nothing would show up when I had a 50x50px image which Facebook didn't complain about in the debugger.  I finally changed the image URL to use a 128x128px one.  It worked even though Facebook complained that the image should be at least 200x200px which I then used.

You can see the fix working [here](https://www.thesuiteq.com)